# Why logs are not syncing to syslogs server from tcp endpoint

Tags: newrelic, syslog, rsyslog

I am creating TCP endpoints for syslogs server and forwarding logs to NewRelic as per rsyslogs configuration

```
$ModLoad imuxsock

module(load="imudp" threads="8" timeRequery="8" batchSize="128")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="sendToNR" )

module(load="imptcp" threads="4")
input(type="imptcp" port="514" ruleset="sendToNR" discardTruncatedMsg="on")

set $/nr_insert_key=`echo $NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY`;

template(name="newrelic-rfc5424"
         type="string"
         string="%$/nr_insert_key% <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %hostname% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% %structured-data% %msg%\n"
)

global(DefaultNetstreamDriver="gtls"
       DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
)

ruleset(name="sendToNR"
        queue.type="LinkedList"
        queue.size="250000"
        queue.dequeueBatchSize="4096"
        queue.workerThreads="6"
        queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages="25000"
        queue.spoolDirectory="/logs/queue"
        queue.filename="fwd"
        queue.saveOnShutdown="on"
        ) {
  action(type="omfwd"
       Target="newrelic.syslog.eu.nr-data.net"
       Port="6514"
       Protocol="tcp"
       Template="newrelic-rfc5424"
       ResendLastMSGOnReconnect="on"
       StreamDriver="gtls"
       StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/name"
       StreamDriverPermittedPeers="*.syslog.eu.nr-data.net"
       StreamDriverMode="1"
  )
}
```

I noticed that when I send logs to my syslog server endpoint, they are forwarded to NewRelic promptly. However, I've encountered an issue when I send a high volume of logs, such as over 20,000 logs in 5 minutes, there is a delay of approximately 20 to 30 minutes. On some occasions, when I send 200,000 logs within 30 minutes, the delay extends to 4 or 5 hours. I'm seeking guidance on identifying any misconfigurations or overlooked settings that might be causing this delay.